# Angular material datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I use `<md-datepicker>` in my angularJs app. When I open it, it shows calendar etc, but the background is transparent. How to make it white?

Here is part of the code:

```
 <td class=" padding-right-10">
     <md-datepicker  ng-model="endDate" ng-change="vm.setEndDate(item.id, endDate)" md-placeholder={{vm.getEndDate(item.metadata)}}></md-datepicker>
 </td>
 <td class=" padding-right-10">
     <span class=" padding-right-10" ng-repeat="user in item.assignment">{{user.username}}</span>
 </td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the css files have been loaded.

Comment: hm...I think css for md-datepicker I havn't found. thanks!

Comment: can you tell me what should be in css file? Currencty I have next structure:
Home.controller.js
home.css
home.htm;
In home.css-there is nothing.